# ImportError: cannot import name 'Login' from 'login'

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to make a login system in python and I keep getting this error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Login' from 'login' (C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\pdicegame\venv\lib\site-packages\login\__init__.py)`
I have installed login and I still get this error, I am a beginner to coding so please help me
This is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import login
from login import Login, Register

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self): #local variable classes
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.title("Login")
        self.app.geometry("300x250")
        self.label = Label(self.app, text="Welcome to DiceRoll")
        self.label.place(x=95, y=40)
        self.login = Button(self.app, text="Login", pady=5, padx=30, command=login)
        self.login.place(x=100, y=100)
        self.register = Button(self.app, text="Register", pady=5, padx=20, command=register)
        self.register.place(x=100, y=150)

    def run(self):
        self.app.mainloop()

def login():
    loginTk = Login()
    loginTk.run()

def register():
    regiterTk = Register()
    registerTk.run()

app = MainWindow()
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the entire login module, that fixed it for me.

```
from tkinter import *
import login
from login import *
```